# AKS application gateway ingress hosts and error 502

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have deployed AKS, vnet, application gateway, public ip using terraform on azure. I have separate subnets for application gateway and AKS subnet. I have also enabled application gateway with AKS as ingress. Now I am trying to deploy a sample app in aks. using this [yml](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/guestbook/all-in-one/guestbook-all-in-one.yaml). Then applied simple-frontend-ingress.yaml for ingress annotation. Vnet, public ip, app gateway, aks, security group are in same resource group. agent pool, identies, load balancer are in other group. I have not done peering as app gateway and aks both are in same group. dns name is attachhed to public ip. Now I am gettingempty hosts in ingress. When I try to create things manually from console, I can see application working. With my terraform code and kubectl apply I see error 502 in dns name. also empty hosts. Also no entry in backend pool. I followed many [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74491462/error-502-after-changing-the-application-gateway-in-the-aks-application-gateway), may be I need to open some port or like that, but not able to resolve same. Application gateway subnet and other subent do not have any security group and route table.

```
kubectl create -f guestbook-all-in-one.yaml

kubectl apply -f simple-frontend-ingress.yaml

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: simple-frontend-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend
            port: 
              number: 80
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
ashish [ ~ ]$ kubectl get ingress
NAME                      CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS         PORTS   AGE
simple-frontend-ingress   <none>   *       20.xxx.xx.201   80      13s


ashish [ ~ ]$ kubectl get service
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
frontend        NodePort    10.20.0.xxx   <none>        80:31157/TCP   24m
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.20.0.x     <none>        443/TCP        52m
redis-master    ClusterIP   10.20.0.2xx   <none>        6379/TCP       24m
redis-replica   ClusterIP   10.20.0.1xx   <none>        6379/TCP       24m


ashish [ ~ ]$ kubectl describe service frontend
Name:                     frontend
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=guestbook
                          tier=frontend
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=guestbook,tier=frontend
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.20.0.110
IPs:                      10.20.0.110
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31157/TCP
Endpoints:                10.10.1.103:80,10.10.1.50:80,10.10.1.90:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ingress Gateway managed identity was missing permission to vnet, AKS cluster. I got this from ingress pod logs. I can delete this question as it was architectural mistake.